# Подставить данные из константы в input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я хочу, чтобы значения брались из константы и подставлялись в input, но я не знаю, как писать код на js. Я попытался пройтись по массиву, но это не сработало.
HTML

```
 <div class="edit__content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form action="" class="form__edit" id="average">
                    <div class="field__container">
                        <label for="fName">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field__container">
                        <label for="lName">Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field__container">
                        <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
                        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field__container">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field__container">
                        <label for="compN">Company name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="compN" name="compN">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field__container">
                        <label for="jobT">Job Title</label>
                        <input type="text" id="jobT" name="jobT">
                    </div>
                    <div class="edit__buttons">
                        <input class="button__edit" id="editButton" type="submit" value="Edit">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="edit__buttons">
                    <a href="./table.html"><button class="button__back">Back</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Есть константа со значениями, но я не понимаю, как подставить значения во ввод, чтобы при входе в форму выводились данные из константы прямо в input.
JS

```
const person = {
    fName: "John",
    lName: "Rambo",
    phone: "+7 (999) 999-99-99",
    email: "johnrambo@gmail.ru",
    compN: "U.S.A. ARMY",
    jobT: "Soldier"
};

console.log(person.fName + " " + person.lname + ", " + person.compN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const person = {
  fName: "John",
  lName: "Rambo",
  phone: "+7 (999) 999-99-99",
  email: "johnrambo@gmail.ru",
  compN: "U.S.A. ARMY",
  jobT: "Soldier"
};

for (let key in person) {
  document.getElementById(key).value = person[key];
}
```

```html
<div class="edit__content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form action="" class="form__edit" id="average">
        <div class="field__container">
          <label for="fName">First name</label>
          <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName">
        </div>
        <div class="field__container">
          <label for="lName">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName">
        </div>
        <div class="field__container">
          <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
          <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="field__container">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="field__container">
          <label for="compN">Company name</label>
          <input type="text" id="compN" name="compN">
        </div>
        <div class="field__container">
          <label for="jobT">Job Title</label>
          <input type="text" id="jobT" name="jobT">
        </div>
        <div class="edit__buttons">
          <input class="button__edit" id="editButton" type="submit" value="Edit">
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="edit__buttons">
        <a href="./table.html"><button class="button__back">Back</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```